# How can i make a toast when user swipes to first fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have three fragments. When the user is on the third fragment and he swipes to the second fragment I want a toast to show up. Is that possible ?

Comment: if you are using tab layout with view pager then try adding viewpager.addOnPageChanged Listener

Comment: yeah that would work but i don't want for example when he goes from the 2nd tab to the 1st for the toast to show up

Comment: try passing some bundle or argument line fragment number while moving between fragments and when desired argument is not found donot generate toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a toast anytime the fragment becomes visible, then use `onResume` in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Make your toast here
}
```

But in case you are particular about the previous fragment, use a static variable in the `Activity` containing the fragments.

For example, if the activity is named `MainAvtivity`:

```
class MainAvtivity extends Activity {
    static int currentFrag = -1;
    ....
}
```

Then, in the `onResume` method of the fragment, do something like:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(MainActivity.currentFrag == 3)
        //Make toast here
    MainActivity.currentFrag = <current_fragment_number>;
}
```